# Как обновить ListView во фрагменте?

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть ListView который отображает информацию из локальной БД. В локальную БД записывается информация которая поступает с сервера. Нужно обновлять ListView каждый раз когда добавляется новая информация в локальную БД.

Вот код адаптера `ListViewAdapter.class`:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessengeItem>{
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<MessengeItem> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.text_item, list);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MessengeItem messengeItem = (MessengeItem) getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text_item, null);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author)).setText(messengeItem.getAuthor());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messenge)).setText(messengeItem.getMessenge());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Код создания фрагмента `MessageTabFragment.class`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);

    this.mes = new ArrayList<>();
    DataBaseAction.initContext(getContext().getApplicationContext());
    mes = DataBaseAction.getMessenge();

    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getContext().getApplicationContext(), mes);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("User", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferences.getString("Login", null);
    et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send);
    initBtnLisiner();
    return view;
}
```

А это сама синхронизация Sync.class :

```
private void updateMessage(){
    ServerAction.getMessages(LinkAPI.GET_ALL_MESSAGE);
    List<MessengeItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    DataBaseAction.initContext(getApplicationContext());
    list = DataBaseAction.getMessenge();
    ListViewAdapter lv = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
    lv.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Почему-то `notifyDataSetChanged()` не обновляет, может я не там его вызываю?

**Изменения в `updateMessage() :`**

`private void updateMessage(final ListView lv){
        ServerAction.getMessages(LinkAPI.GET_ALL_MESSAGE);
        List<MessengeItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        DataBaseAction.initContext(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        list = DataBaseAction.getMessenge();
        final ListViewAdapter ad = new 
        ListViewAdapter(getContext().getApplicationContext(),list);
        lv.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lv.setAdapter(ad);
                }
        });
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создаёте адаптер, но не присваиваете его `ListView`. Оттого и нема изменений в нём.

Скорее всего вам надо не создавать каждый раз новый адаптер, а изменять текущий, обновляя данные в нём и вызывая у него notifyDataSetChanged для перерисовки

Comment: и как мне лист вью переопределить через findviewbyid() когда у меня это в сервисе?
Ладно, updateMessage() вытащил из сервиса и засунул во фрагмент. указываю листвью адаптер, а он ругается при назначении listview адаптера.
    `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: @ГлебШушарин, эта ошибка означает, что вы не из основного потока манипулируете элементами разметки. Скорее всего вам достаточно будет обернуть падающий код в `getActivity().runOnUiTread(new Runnable(){ /* тут код выполниться в главном потоке */ });`

Comment: Точно, не сообразил сразу, Благодарствую

Comment: первоначально listview отображается с низу, а при обнавлении отображается сверху, как это можно исправить?
добавил код сверху

Comment: @ГлебШушарин. когда у вас возникает новый вопрос, то его по правилам сайта надо задавать в отдельном вопросе. Не надо превращать этот вопрос в список вопросов)